# What driver should I install for AMD Radeon Vega 3 and how? - Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, radeon, 21.10

Today I bought a small, used 11" laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 1 with AMD Athlon Silver 3050E (Zen+) with Radeon Vega 3. What drivers should I install and how? I want to play some less demanding 3D games.

When I checked Additional Drivers in Ubuntu, there are no proprietary drivers there.

Also, I can't find any drivers for Linux on AMD's Download page.

I'm new to linux so I'm requesting detailed, step by step instructions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need any additional drivers. All is installed already.

Comment: So, how do I check what driver I have installed, just for the learning's sake?

Comment: The driver is included in the kernel. It is called `amdgpu`. You can see it by `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'Display|VGA'`, or in system properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drivers for AMD GPUs are included in Linux kernel. There is no need to install anything.

There are `amdgpu-pro` drivers that can be installed for some models, but in 99% of cases there is no benefit. Also not all kernels and GPU models are supported.

AMD didn't release Pro drivers for Ryzen 3 as far as I know.